# Sum of subharmonic functions attaining a maximum in an open, connected set.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I want to prove the following statement: If $p_1,..,p_n$ are subharmonic functions on an open, connected subset $V$ of the complex plane and if $p_1+...+p_n$ attains a maximum on $V$, then each $p_i$ is a harmonic function.

My attempt: The sum $p_1+...+p_n$ is subharmonic. And so by the maximum principle for subharmonic functions, it is a constant. Therefore, $\Delta(p_1+...+p_n)=\Delta(p_1)+...+\Delta(p_n)=0$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator. I don't see how this forces $\Delta(p_i)=0$, for each $i$.

Also at my disposal are the mean value properties of harmonic and subharmonic functions, but I can't see a way to employ them. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: $\Delta(p_k) \ge 0$ for subharmonic functions so if their sum is zero, each is zero; all can be reformulated in terms of means as each has the submean property, but the sum has the mean property, so each must have the mean property to get equality when added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already demonstrated that
$$
 p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n = C
$$
is constant. Then both $p_1$ and
$$
 -p_1 = p_2 + \cdots + p_n - C
$$
are subharmonic, which means that $p_1$ is harmonic.

The same arguments works for $p_2, \ldots, p_n$.